# can we able to save a file from a person's skydrive account into our skydrive account without downloading?

Tags: onedrive

I'm Studying about the Microsoft's SkyDrive. Is it possible to copy or move a public file from a person account to our own SkyDrive account...

If it is there somebody tell me, how could do that. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible, you have to download the file and share to other person.